# Linux Ubuntu doesn't recognise my bluetooth dongle even tho I was able to use it on Windows 10

Tags: bluetooth

I tried executing the solution from this link here where you copy the ar3k folder into lib/firmware. In lib/firmware there was already a folder called "ar3k". I tried it either way but I didn't have permission.
It was recommended to me to use terminal and try "sudo cp ar3k  /lib/firmware/rtlwifi"
which resulted in this:
Edit: 
"cannot stat'ar3k': no such file or directory"

Now how do I solve this problem:

1. don't bc the ar3k folder was already in lib/firmware so no point in doing that?
2. get permission and copy that file in there (if yes, how do I do that?)
3. It's bc of the drivers so i don't have to even bother trying

I am completely new to Linux so if at all possible pls try to make the answer as understandable for dummies as possible

Thank you

Edits:
This is the output of the command 'lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue:
output :'operation not permitted'

Disabled fast startup for windows

Comment: When dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. Do that and shutdown Windows. Boot Ubuntu and test.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: `ar3k` is specific to some devices. You need to start with identification of your device. And the `ar3k` solution is obsolete, because that has been fixed already.

Comment: Also please don't post screenshots of text. Terminal output is a plain text.